# Bug in windows bluetooth le GetGattServicesAsync method

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

Sometimes it is not possible to get some response from the method `GetGattServicesAsync` with the parameter `BluetoothCacheMode.Cached` or `BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached`. Only the windows restart helps to reconnect the le device and to get the services from the le device.

We use `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll` with .Net Framework 4.6.1 to build the class library. The Windows PC shall connect the Bluetooth le device.

**Steps for the problem reproducing:**

1. Discovery the devices with the determined service
2. Call the method `FromBluetoothAddressAsync` with the Bluetooth address of LE device
3. BluetoothLEDevice is found
4. Pair the LE device with desktop:

   ```
   DeviceInformationPairing loPairingInf = poDevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing;
   if (!loPairingInf.IsPaired)
   {
       DevicePairingKinds loConfirm = DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly;
       DevicePairingProtectionLevel loProtectionLevel = DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Default;
       DeviceInformationCustomPairing loCustomPairing = loPairingInf.Custom;
   }
   ```
5. Check the connection status. If the status connected, call the method `GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Cached)`. Sometimes is not possible to get the response from `GetGattServicesAsync`. After 30 seconds we cancel the task, dispose `BluetoothLEDevice`, unpair and try to reconnect le device. The reconnection is failed and only the windows restart helps to establish the connection to the le device.

**PC:**

- Dell Precision 5530
- Bluetooth adapter Qualcomm QCA6174A
- Windows 10 Enterprise (1803)
- Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134.590

**LE Device:**

- Bluetooth 4.2

**Question:**

- Is it possible to avoid the problem with  GetGattServicesAsync ?
- Maybe exists some programmatically hack to reconnect the le device
  after the GetGattServicesAsync canceling without the restart windows?

Comment: Do not pair with BLE device.

Answer (score 0):

I found some System Services are related to this issue.

You can try to restart the `Bluetooth Support Service` in  TaskManager.

If you want to identify the process from TaskManager, the command line of this service is

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalService -p -s bthserv

This workaround is not perfect, but slightly better than restarting the computer.

However, remember to call `BluetoothLEDevice.Dispose` if you want to close the connection to BluetoothLE device. Otherwise, you may encounter some other issue in the one process.

Comment: As well as calling `BluetoothLEDevice.Dispose`, also call `GattDeviceService.Dispose`.